# Adding photos to columns

Tags: html, css, layout, photo

I am trying to create a director's tribute page as a newbie and having an issue to align photos in the column. First, I have dived my layout in two-column and tried to write Infos on left, and insert photos on the right side. Problem is `#best-scenes` ID not working properly, defining column-gap, column-rule-color... Please see the image from Chrome to see how it looks like. I tried to add absolute/relative too but didn't work it out.

Thanks in advance.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  color: #32815b;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #08500b;
}

#portrait_image {
  text-align: center;
  height: 300px;
}

#image {
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

#img-caption {
  font-family: "Nunito Semibold";
  font-size: 10px;
}

#content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
}

#Best-scenes {
  column-count: 2;
  column-rule-color: #e6e6e7;
  column-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title"> Wong Kar Wai </h1>
<div id="img-div">
  <img src="images/wongkarwai_portrait.jpg" alt="Wong Kar Wai Portrait" id="portrait_image">
  <p id="img-caption">
    <em>Portrait of Wong Kar Wai</em> </p>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="tribute-info">
    <p>Wong Kar-wai (born 17 July 1956) is a Hong Kong Second Wave filmmaker, internationally renowned as an auteur for his visually unique, highly stylised, emotionally resonant work, including Ah fei zing zyun (1990), Dung che sai duk (1994), Chung Hing
      sam lam (1994), Do lok tin si (1995), Chun gwong cha sit (1997), 2046 (2004) and My Blueberry Nights (2007), Yi dai zong shi (2013). His film Fa yeung nin wa (2000), starring Maggie Cheung and Tony Leung, garnered widespread critical acclaim. Wong's
      films frequently feature protagonists who yearn for romance in the midst of a knowingly brief life and scenes that can often be described as sketchy, digressive, exhilarating, and containing vivid imagery. Wong was the first Chinese director to
      win the Best Director Award of Cannes Film Festival (for his work Chun gwong cha sit in 1997). Wong was the President of the Jury at the 2006 Cannes Film Festival, which makes him the only Chinese person to preside over the jury at the Cannes Film
      Festival. He was also the President of the Jury at the 63rd Berlin International Film Festival in February 2013. In 2006, Wong accepted the National Order of the Legion of Honour: Knight (Highest Degree) from the French Government. In 2013, Wong
      accepted Order of Arts and Letters: Commander (Highest Degree) by the French Minister of Culture.</p>

  </div>
  <div id="Best-scenes">
    <h2> Best Scenes of Wai </h2>
    <div><img src="images/1.png" alt="Wong Kar Wai Portrait" id="image"></div>
    <div><img src="images/d961eb00-4c74-11e9-8e02-95b31fc3f54a_image_hires_162650.jpg" alt="movie_scene" id="image"></div>
    <div><img src="images/Days-of-Being-Wild.jpg" alt="movie_scene" id="image"></div>
    <div><img src="images/Happy-Together.jpg" alt="movie_scene" id="image"></div>
    <div><img src="images/in_the_mood_for_love.jpg" alt="movie_scene" id="image"></div>
    <div><img src="images/In-The-Mood-For-Love-1.jpg" alt="movie_scene" id="image"></div>
    <div><img src="images/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="movie_scene" id="image"></div>
    <div><img src="images/ndywmhpclyyhznfljwgn.jpg" alt="movie_scene" id="image"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- <div id="footer">
    <a href="https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0939182/bio?ref_=nm_ov_bio_sm" target="_blank" id="tribute-link">
      Learn more about Wong Kar Wai
  </div> -->
```

[image: Screenshot_browser]

Comment: Please update question about images with images from for example placeholder.com

Comment: What is the layout you are trying to achieve? It will help to include an illustration/figure on what the desired layout should look like. It's difficult to guess from your question.

Comment: hello @Terry, I am trying have 2 columns for 8 photos in total, I don`t know how the gap between two columns happened. [reference photo] https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/grid-close-ups-smiling-people-44412482.jpg

Comment: You need to change `column-count: 2` into one column `column-count: 1`! Inside the #Best-scenes you need one column if I understand it right, otherwise, it is shown already into two columns; Please clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

you have to add:

```
#Best-scenes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: this adds given me one column instead of 2. but i have column-count: 2; thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
#image
{
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}
```

I found a solution by changing the sizes of photos in the column. But still don't understand why that `object-position: center;` is not working in this case.